# finding DateOFBirth From Age

Tags: android, iphone, objective-c

Is there any formula to direct finding D.O.B from put Year,month and day's in TextField ??
InShort put 21 year 6 month 16 day in text filed that return the calculating D.O.B ?

Comment: you could use the current date as a reference and calculate it !

Comment: What Have You Tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Do you want it in _iPhone_, _Android_ and _Java_, all three of them?

Comment: http://www.mathcats.com/explore/age/calculator.html

Comment: ya the current date as a reference for calculate it

Comment: in that link the convert is opposite i want to get dob from the putting Age

Comment: i have a application that for uneducated people of villages,they does't know eject it's Dob so they give to only year or month that why it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iphone you do not have direct method how ever you can write on your own.

step 1: Make a NSDate object from year,month,day.

```
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comp setYear:year];
[comp setMonth:month];
[comp setDay:day];
 NSDate *birthdate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comp];
[comp release];
```

step 2: Find the interval from from today.

```
NSTimeInterval dateDiff = [birthDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
int age=trunc(dateDiff/(60*60*24))/365;
```

EDIT ...

```
    NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comp setYear:-year];
    [comp setMonth:-month];
    [comp setDay:-day];
     NSDate *birthdate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];;
    [comp release];
```

Comment: @ravi: Firstly, I think Step-1 doesn't calculate correct birthdate.Secondly, I think you want Birthdate from age and **not** date from birthdate. Am I right?

Comment: @ParthBhatt. You are correct. I will update the answer in a moment.

Comment: @parth ya i cant get correct D.O.B but it's near to approximate date of Birth but month any year must return true

Answer (score 2):

...In Java...
I like to use Calendar for this operations. In your case I recommend you to use the [add method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29)

So you should create a new instance of Calendar with current date, set the day and the month, and then substract the age.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println();
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -21);
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -16);
    System.out.println((c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+ c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"-"+c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it is more useful

Just enter the two dates it gives the difference.

```
 NSDateComponents *comp=[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:self.objDate options:0] ;

 NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d : %d : %d : %d : %d",comp.year,comp.month,comp.day,comp.hour,comp.minute,comp.second]);
```

Following code may helping to you.

Happy coding